# How to use git to transfer uncommitted changes from one machine to another?

Tags: git

I often work on my desktop and end up with changes not worthy of a commit. I want to then switch to my laptop and continue work where I left off on my desktop (including all uncommitted changes). How do I best do this with git?

I almost, like, wanna do a temporary commit, pull that, then undo the commit both locally and remotely as if it never ever happened. Is this the approach or is it something else? And how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, what you've described is exactly what you'd need to do.

The notion of Git doing anything with "uncommitted changes" makes no sense at all, because commits are the only thing Git traffics in. Therefore you *must* commit in order to do the transfer.

---

So just make a commit, give it a useful message like `wip`, and push. Once you've pulled onto the other machine, if you don't want to preserve that commit, you can "undo" it as a commit by saying

```
git reset @~1
```

...but be advised that if you do that, then later on you will need to *force* push in order to carry on.

---

Perhaps a better approach, because it avoids the force push, is to make a temporary branch:

```
git switch -c wip
git add .
git commit -m wip
git push

# and on the other machine

git fetch origin
git switch wip
git reset main # or wherever you were working when you created wip
git switch main # or wherever you were working
git branch -D wip
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I wanted to ask. I tried this very thing a few weeks ago but it ended up in me having to force push. I found that very awkward. Why was that the case? Doesn't that mean the "undo" step was done incorrectly?

Comment: Should I maybe force push right after running `git reset`? Does that also do the trick?

Comment: There's no "trick". Basically it's just a matter of understanding what you're doing. Your reset rewrites history and you will have to force push to proceed. You can do it now or later, it doesn't matter. I've added a more elaborate approach that avoids the force push.

Comment: And the force push just means, "hey remote, go override your history with my modified one, no questions asked"?

Comment: That's correct. It is wrong to do this with a shared branch that others might be using, but if this is just you sending stuff to yourself it is totally cool.

Comment: Alright, used the reset + force approach. Worked. Thank you!

Comment: "_The notion of Git doing anything with "uncommitted changes" makes no sense at all_" -- I mean, `git diff` certainly does. So does `git commit` iirc. `;^D` It's just a tool. If `wip` and "undo" is the best way to do it, that's clever and effective, but it wouldn't be ontologically nonsensical for git to have a command that transfers full state.

Comment: @ruffin Upvoted for saying "ontologically".

Answer (score 1):

You can always just create a new commit and push that to a (temorary) branch. As matt noted, you should not do this on a shared branch and you have to rewind your local branch after the push:

```
git commit -am 'temp work'
git push origin HEAD:refs/heads/temp
git reset HEAD^
```

At least the rewinding part could be replaced by a clever alias:

```
git config --global alias.pushtemp '!git add -u && git push origin +$(git write-tree):refs/heads/temp'
```

And then just call `git pushtemp`. NB. the `pushtemp` alias force-pushes to the `temp` branch, overwriting anything that is different on your remote. It's easy to lose work that way. Remove the `+` to do a normal push.